# Assertion failed on spark using GeoSpark

Tags: java, apache-spark, geospark

I have the following dataframe :

```
+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|longitude_f   |  latitude_f       |   geom              |
+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|7.0737816     |33.82666           |   00 00 00 00 01 0..|
|-7.6198783    |33.5942549         |   00 00 00 00 01 0..|
+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+

longitude_f : double ----
latitude_f  : double ----
geom        : geometry ----
```

When I execute the following code :

```
Dataset <Row> result_f = sparkSession.sql("select * from data_f where ST_Within(ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude_f,' ',latitude_f,')',4326)),geom)");
 result_f.show();
```

I get the following exception :

```
20/08/01 19:50:36 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 87.0 in stage 40.0 (TID 930)
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.sql.geosparksql.expressions.ST_PolygonFromEnvelope.eval(Constructors.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.sql.geosparksql.expressions.ST_Within.eval(Predicates.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate.And_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate.eval(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.CartesianProductExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(CartesianProductExec.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.CartesianProductExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(CartesianProductExec.scala:88)
```

I need your help .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`ST_PolygonFromEnvelope` takes 4 args and they have assertion which is failing

```
assert(inputExpressions.length == 4)
```

provide 4 input arguments to this function and proceed.
On a side note, i would suggest download the source from git and check these.
Also refer the documentation, I think, you are not doing that

Comment: thank you for your reply , have you any idea
why when we read a geometry type in mysql becomes binary type in spark ?

Comment: I don't have any idea.